Codespace to personal server
If I take the code from a codespace and run it on my own server will it go inative?
I am running a small Minecraft server for me and a few friends, but codespaces go inactive alot. Will it go inactive if I run it on my own server?
I've looked it up, but am worried if I try it it could mess with the world

I don't know anything about Minecraft, but I suspect it'll just run. Have you tried it?
